# Can't manually remove angular material md-autocomplete element from dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-material

When trying to remove autocomplete element by esc or blur, and destroying its scope this way (stopEdit is called on click outside or esc keycode event):

```
 function stopEdit() {
  autoCompleteController.clear();
  autoCompleteController.blur();
  $timeout(function () {
    if (angular.isDefined($attrs.ngBind)) {
      $element.empty();
      $element.text($scope.$eval($attrs.ngBind));
    }

    input = undefined;
    autoCompleteController = undefined;
    if (inputScope) {
      inputScope.$destroy();
      inputScope = undefined;
    }

    $element.removeClass('autocomplete-input-active');
    angular.element('body').off('click', clickOutsideHandler);
    angular.element('.md-scroll-mask').css({
      position: 'initial'
    });
  }, 100); //here I've added timeout, which make code work, but it's not really good solution
}
```

error falling:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$setViewValue' of undefined
at angular-material.js:18874
at processQueue (angular.js:14745)
at angular.js:14761
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15989)
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15800)
at angular.js:16028
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5507)
at angular.js:5784
```

Is there way to destroy scope properly in this case, or wait while directive will complete its internal escape event handling?

Comment: please show all relevant code. Not entirely clear what you are trying to do either

Comment: Added code. I'm trying to completely remove autocomplete directive from dom on escape or blur, replacing it by text.

Comment: can't you toggle it using something like `ng-if` or `ng-switch`?

Comment: hmm, well, there's quite a huge table with editable cells, how will large amount of ng-ifs, with their own scopes, will affect performance?

Comment: Could just use `$compile` on rows when you switch

Comment: Tried. Got same error, when autocomplete was destroyed by ngif set to false.

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem